# How can I make Javascript Countdown can perform two or more in one page?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have javascript countdown code bellow:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "12/31/2015 8:00 AM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.katalogbukunasional.com/anekadata/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

I want the code to perform 2 or more in a single page, like this:

- Student Test for ELEMENTER SCHOOL: .... countdown here ...
- Student Test for JUNIOR SCHOOL : .... countdown here ....
- Student Test for HIGHT SCHOOL  : .... countdown here ....

DEMO:

- one code in one page (WORK):
  http://katalogbukunasional.com/anekadata/demo/1code.html
- two code in one page (NOT WORK)
  http://katalogbukunasional.com/anekadata/demo/2code.html

What code should I add? Or is there another countdown code is best?

Comment: You're not even showing us your countdown code; just a bit of html that includes a JS file. How are we supposed to help you here?

Comment: You are using document.getElementById to get a reference to your dom elements. IDs are meant to uniquely define elements, so two elements cannot have the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly was going on with the demo pages you posted, but I think I understand what you're looking for.  I looked at the documentation and made a fiddle.

HTML:

```
<span id="pageTimer1"></span>
<br />
<span id="pageTimer2"></span>
```

JS:

```
var timerId1 = countdown(new Date(2015,5,31,0,6,0,0), function (ts) {
    document.getElementById('pageTimer1').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
},
countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);

var timerId2 = countdown(new Date(2016,5,31,0,6,0,0), function (ts) {
    document.getElementById('pageTimer2').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
},
countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);
```

```js
/*
 countdown.js v2.5.2 http://countdownjs.org
 Copyright (c)2006-2014 Stephen M. McKamey.
 Licensed under The MIT License.
*/
var module,countdown=function(y){function C(a,b){var c=a.getTime();a.setMonth(a.getMonth()+b);return Math.round((a.getTime()-c)/864E5)}function z(a){var b=a.getTime(),c=new Date(b);c.setMonth(a.getMonth()+1);return Math.round((c.getTime()-b)/864E5)}function A(a,b){b=b instanceof Date||null!==b&&isFinite(b)?new Date(+b):new Date;if(!a)return b;var c=+a.value||0;if(c)return b.setTime(b.getTime()+c),b;(c=+a.milliseconds||0)&&b.setMilliseconds(b.getMilliseconds()+c);(c=+a.seconds||0)&&b.setSeconds(b.getSeconds()+
c);(c=+a.minutes||0)&&b.setMinutes(b.getMinutes()+c);(c=+a.hours||0)&&b.setHours(b.getHours()+c);(c=+a.weeks||0)&&(c*=7);(c+=+a.days||0)&&b.setDate(b.getDate()+c);(c=+a.months||0)&&b.setMonth(b.getMonth()+c);(c=+a.millennia||0)&&(c*=10);(c+=+a.centuries||0)&&(c*=10);(c+=+a.decades||0)&&(c*=10);(c+=+a.years||0)&&b.setFullYear(b.getFullYear()+c);return b}function l(a,b){return v(a)+(1===a?w[b]:x[b])}function q(){}function n(a,b,c,d,f,m){0<=a[c]&&(b+=a[c],delete a[c]);b/=f;if(1>=b+1)return 0;if(0<=a[d]){a[d]=
+(a[d]+b).toFixed(m);switch(d){case "seconds":if(60!==a.seconds||isNaN(a.minutes))break;a.minutes++;a.seconds=0;case "minutes":if(60!==a.minutes||isNaN(a.hours))break;a.hours++;a.minutes=0;case "hours":if(24!==a.hours||isNaN(a.days))break;a.days++;a.hours=0;case "days":if(7!==a.days||isNaN(a.weeks))break;a.weeks++;a.days=0;case "weeks":if(a.weeks!==z(a.refMonth)/7||isNaN(a.months))break;a.months++;a.weeks=0;case "months":if(12!==a.months||isNaN(a.years))break;a.years++;a.months=0;case "years":if(10!==
a.years||isNaN(a.decades))break;a.decades++;a.years=0;case "decades":if(10!==a.decades||isNaN(a.centuries))break;a.centuries++;a.decades=0;case "centuries":if(10!==a.centuries||isNaN(a.millennia))break;a.millennia++;a.centuries=0}return 0}return b}function D(a,b,c,d,f,m){var k=new Date;a.start=b=b||k;a.end=c=c||k;a.units=d;a.value=c.getTime()-b.getTime();0>a.value&&(k=c,c=b,b=k);a.refMonth=new Date(b.getFullYear(),b.getMonth(),15,12,0,0);try{a.millennia=0;a.centuries=0;a.decades=0;a.years=c.getFullYear()-
b.getFullYear();a.months=c.getMonth()-b.getMonth();a.weeks=0;a.days=c.getDate()-b.getDate();a.hours=c.getHours()-b.getHours();a.minutes=c.getMinutes()-b.getMinutes();a.seconds=c.getSeconds()-b.getSeconds();a.milliseconds=c.getMilliseconds()-b.getMilliseconds();var g;0>a.milliseconds?(g=s(-a.milliseconds/1E3),a.seconds-=g,a.milliseconds+=1E3*g):1E3<=a.milliseconds&&(a.seconds+=p(a.milliseconds/1E3),a.milliseconds%=1E3);0>a.seconds?(g=s(-a.seconds/60),a.minutes-=g,a.seconds+=60*g):60<=a.seconds&&(a.minutes+=
p(a.seconds/60),a.seconds%=60);0>a.minutes?(g=s(-a.minutes/60),a.hours-=g,a.minutes+=60*g):60<=a.minutes&&(a.hours+=p(a.minutes/60),a.minutes%=60);0>a.hours?(g=s(-a.hours/24),a.days-=g,a.hours+=24*g):24<=a.hours&&(a.days+=p(a.hours/24),a.hours%=24);for(;0>a.days;)a.months--,a.days+=C(a.refMonth,1);7<=a.days&&(a.weeks+=p(a.days/7),a.days%=7);0>a.months?(g=s(-a.months/12),a.years-=g,a.months+=12*g):12<=a.months&&(a.years+=p(a.months/12),a.months%=12);10<=a.years&&(a.decades+=p(a.years/10),a.years%=
10,10<=a.decades&&(a.centuries+=p(a.decades/10),a.decades%=10,10<=a.centuries&&(a.millennia+=p(a.centuries/10),a.centuries%=10)));b=0;!(d&1024)||b>=f?(a.centuries+=10*a.millennia,delete a.millennia):a.millennia&&b++;!(d&512)||b>=f?(a.decades+=10*a.centuries,delete a.centuries):a.centuries&&b++;!(d&256)||b>=f?(a.years+=10*a.decades,delete a.decades):a.decades&&b++;!(d&128)||b>=f?(a.months+=12*a.years,delete a.years):a.years&&b++;!(d&64)||b>=f?(a.months&&(a.days+=C(a.refMonth,a.months)),delete a.months,
7<=a.days&&(a.weeks+=p(a.days/7),a.days%=7)):a.months&&b++;!(d&32)||b>=f?(a.days+=7*a.weeks,delete a.weeks):a.weeks&&b++;!(d&16)||b>=f?(a.hours+=24*a.days,delete a.days):a.days&&b++;!(d&8)||b>=f?(a.minutes+=60*a.hours,delete a.hours):a.hours&&b++;!(d&4)||b>=f?(a.seconds+=60*a.minutes,delete a.minutes):a.minutes&&b++;!(d&2)||b>=f?(a.milliseconds+=1E3*a.seconds,delete a.seconds):a.seconds&&b++;if(!(d&1)||b>=f){var h=n(a,0,"milliseconds","seconds",1E3,m);if(h&&(h=n(a,h,"seconds","minutes",60,m))&&(h=
n(a,h,"minutes","hours",60,m))&&(h=n(a,h,"hours","days",24,m))&&(h=n(a,h,"days","weeks",7,m))&&(h=n(a,h,"weeks","months",z(a.refMonth)/7,m))){d=h;var e,l=a.refMonth,q=l.getTime(),r=new Date(q);r.setFullYear(l.getFullYear()+1);e=Math.round((r.getTime()-q)/864E5);if(h=n(a,d,"months","years",e/z(a.refMonth),m))if(h=n(a,h,"years","decades",10,m))if(h=n(a,h,"decades","centuries",10,m))if(h=n(a,h,"centuries","millennia",10,m))throw Error("Fractional unit overflow");}}}finally{delete a.refMonth}return a}
function e(a,b,c,d,f){var e;c=+c||222;d=0<d?d:NaN;f=0<f?20>f?Math.round(f):20:0;var k=null;"function"===typeof a?(e=a,a=null):a instanceof Date||(null!==a&&isFinite(a)?a=new Date(+a):("object"===typeof k&&(k=a),a=null));var g=null;"function"===typeof b?(e=b,b=null):b instanceof Date||(null!==b&&isFinite(b)?b=new Date(+b):("object"===typeof b&&(g=b),b=null));k&&(a=A(k,b));g&&(b=A(g,a));if(!a&&!b)return new q;if(!e)return D(new q,a,b,c,d,f);var k=c&1?1E3/30:c&2?1E3:c&4?6E4:c&8?36E5:c&16?864E5:6048E5,
h,g=function(){e(D(new q,a,b,c,d,f),h)};g();return h=setInterval(g,k)}var s=Math.ceil,p=Math.floor,w,x,r,t,u,v,B;q.prototype.toString=function(a){var b=B(this),c=b.length;if(!c)return a?""+a:u;if(1===c)return b[0];a=r+b.pop();return b.join(t)+a};q.prototype.toHTML=function(a,b){a=a||"span";var c=B(this),d=c.length;if(!d)return(b=b||u)?"\x3c"+a+"\x3e"+b+"\x3c/"+a+"\x3e":b;for(var f=0;f<d;f++)c[f]="\x3c"+a+"\x3e"+c[f]+"\x3c/"+a+"\x3e";if(1===d)return c[0];d=r+c.pop();return c.join(t)+d};q.prototype.addTo=
function(a){return A(this,a)};B=function(a){var b=[],c=a.millennia;c&&b.push(l(c,10));(c=a.centuries)&&b.push(l(c,9));(c=a.decades)&&b.push(l(c,8));(c=a.years)&&b.push(l(c,7));(c=a.months)&&b.push(l(c,6));(c=a.weeks)&&b.push(l(c,5));(c=a.days)&&b.push(l(c,4));(c=a.hours)&&b.push(l(c,3));(c=a.minutes)&&b.push(l(c,2));(c=a.seconds)&&b.push(l(c,1));(c=a.milliseconds)&&b.push(l(c,0));return b};e.MILLISECONDS=1;e.SECONDS=2;e.MINUTES=4;e.HOURS=8;e.DAYS=16;e.WEEKS=32;e.MONTHS=64;e.YEARS=128;e.DECADES=256;
e.CENTURIES=512;e.MILLENNIA=1024;e.DEFAULTS=222;e.ALL=2047;e.setLabels=function(a,b,c,d,f,e){a=a||[];a.split&&(a=a.split("|"));b=b||[];b.split&&(b=b.split("|"));for(var k=0;10>=k;k++)w[k]=a[k]||w[k],x[k]=b[k]||x[k];r="string"===typeof c?c:r;t="string"===typeof d?d:t;u="string"===typeof f?f:u;v="function"===typeof e?e:v};(e.resetLabels=function(){w=" millisecond; second; minute; hour; day; week; month; year; decade; century; millennium".split(";");x=" milliseconds; seconds; minutes; hours; days; weeks; months; years; decades; centuries; millennia".split(";");
r=" and ";t=", ";u="";v=function(a){return a}})();y&&y.exports?y.exports=e:"function"===typeof window.define&&"undefined"!==typeof window.define.amd&&window.define("countdown",[],function(){return e});return e}(module);

var timerId1 = countdown(new Date(2015,5,31,0,6,0,0), function (ts) {
    document.getElementById('pageTimer1').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
},
countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);

var timerId2 = countdown(new Date(2016,5,31,0,6,0,0), function (ts) {
    document.getElementById('pageTimer2').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
},
countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);
```

```html
<span id="pageTimer1"></span>
<br />
<span id="pageTimer2"></span>
```

I hope this clears up any confusion.

Side note: I had never heard of this plugin, but I like it a lot.  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I couldn't get the CDN to work so I copy/pasted the plugin's JavaScript.  If anyone can fix that, please go ahead.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for Mr.Joseph Malle. My problem is resolved.